# Creating a Rectangle in GIS using JSON

Tags: geojson

I am trying to use a USGS product called [AppEARS](https://lpdaacsvc.cr.usgs.gov/appeears/task/area) to download data. I want all data across the world, but the interface wants me to specify a region.
[image]

How can I write a JSON file that will allow me to draw a "polygon" that essentially covers the whole map (i.e. from -180 to 180, from -90 to 90)?

Comment: Use the draw rectangle as in your screenshot? (as MrXsquared mentions).

Comment: @Mapperz this is a good suggestion, but unfortunately I could not draw a rectangle big enough to encompass the whole map. The solution I wrote below worked great. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe it's deliberate, to discourage large downloads.

Answer (score 1):

A website where you can write GeoJSON using drag and drop on a map is http://geojson.io/

Global extent would be defined like:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -180,
              -90
            ],
            [
              180,
              -90
            ],
            [
              180,
              90
            ],
            [
              -180,
              90
            ],
            [
              -180,
              -90
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```